# How to collect elements from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to collect elements from an array?

Example:

`array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]`, 
`array2 = [6,7,8,9,10]` and the results creates a new array with the result 
`[7,9,11,13,15]`

```
arrayy = () => {

  var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  var arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  var test = " "
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    test += (arr1[i] + arr2[i]);

  }
  console.log(test);
}
```

Comment: How is setting up a server related to the JS arrays?

Comment: @briosheje I see it was deleted by Tarchy and and not community - or perhaps I do not see the votes

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [asl]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: @mplungjan yep, just wanted to make sure that the repost chain would end there, though :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use array and push the value into it, instead of appending it to string

```js
const arrayy = () => {

  var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  var arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  var test = []                            //  <-- initialize as array
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    test.push(arr1[i] + arr2[i]);          // <-- push values to array 
  }
  console.log(test);
}

arrayy()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `test` variable should be an array which you `.push()` your results to. Instead, you could `.map()` one array's elements to the addition of the others array's element of the same index like so:

```js
const add_arrays = (arr1, arr2) => 
  arr1.map((n, i) => n+arr2[i]);

const array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
const array2 = [6,7,8,9,10];

console.log(add_arrays(array1, array2)); // [7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both arrays will always have the same length, we can do it using `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
const array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
const array2 = [6,7,8,9,10];

const res = array1.reduce((acc, ele, idx) => {
  return acc.concat(ele + +array2[idx]);
}, []);

console.log(res);
```